# A limit containing an integral

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I got stuck evaluating the limit of an expression containing an integral. $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{e^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)\int_{n}^{n+1}e^{x^2}dx}$$

Using Mathematica, I can get the reference answer of $2$. But I don't know how to compute it by hand.

I tried taking Taylor series at $x=n+1$ to cancel $e^{(n+1)^2}$ but it doesn't work - the denominator becomes a polynomial of $n$, so the limit becomes $0$, which is certainly wrong.

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Treat $n$ as a real variable and apply L'Hopital's Rule. After that divide numerator and denominator  by $(n+1)e^{(y+1)^{2}}$ and use the fact that $\int_n^{(n+1)}e^{x^{2}}dx \leq e^{(n+1)^{2}}$

Comment: Treating a discrete variable as continuous really works. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to calculate the OP’s limit.

By using integration by parts, we get that

$\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}\!\!e^{x^2}\mathrm dx=\int_n^{n+1}\!\!\dfrac1{2x}\!\cdot\!2xe^{x^2}\mathrm dx=\left[\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{2x}\right]_n^{n+1}\!\!\!\!\!+\int_n^{n+1}\!\!\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{2x^2}\,\mathrm dx\,.$

Since $\;0<\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}\!\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{2x^2}\,\mathrm dx<\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}{2(n+1)^2}\;,\;$ it follows that

$\displaystyle\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}{2(n+1)}-\dfrac{e^{n^2}}{2n}<\int_n^{n+1}\!\!e^{x^2}\mathrm dx<\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}{2(n+1)}+\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}{2(n+1)^2}\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}2-\dfrac{(n\!+\!1)e^{n^2}}{2n}<(n\!+\!1)\!\int_n^{n+1}\!\!e^{x^2}\mathrm dx<\dfrac{e^{(n+1)^2}}2\left[1+\dfrac1{n\!+\!1}\right]\;,$

$\displaystyle\dfrac12\!-\!\dfrac{n\!+\!1}{2ne^{2n+1}}<\dfrac{(n\!+\!1)\!\!\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}\!\!\!e^{x^2}\mathrm dx}{e^{(n+1)^2}}<\dfrac12\left[1\!+\!\dfrac1{n\!+\!1}\right],\;\;\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,.$

By applying Squeeze theorem, we get that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{(n\!+\!1)\!\displaystyle\int_n^{n+1}\!\!e^{x^2}\mathrm dx}{e^{(n+1)^2}}=\dfrac12\;.$

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment*

It works fine with Taylor assuming the you know that
$$\int_n^{n+1}e^{x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (\text{erfi}(n+1)-\text{erfi}(n))$$ and that you know the series expansion of the imaginary error function.

Now, *(here is the trick)*, conider instead the reciprocal of the expression
$$\frac 1 {A_n}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}  e^{-(n+1)^2}\, (n+1) \,(\text{erfi}(n+1)-\text{erfi}(n))$$ and you should obtain
$$\frac 1 {A_n}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4 n^2}-\frac{1}{2n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)-$$ $$e^{-(2n+1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{4 n^2}+\frac{1}{4 n^3} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Back to $A_n$, we have a very good approximation; for example

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact value} \\
 4 & 1.95852 & 1.96954 \\
 5 & 1.97143 & 1.97632 \\
 6 & 1.97916 & 1.98166 \\
 7 & 1.98412 & 1.98553 \\
 8 & 1.98750 & 1.98835 \\
 9 & 1.98990 & 1.99044 \\
 10 & 1.99167 & 1.99203 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$